# Ext js 3.4 window add/remove Component error

Tags: layout, components, addition, extjs3

We are using extjs 3.4. The purpose is to replace a component in a Ext.Window. Even if 
there is no error when we remove the old and add the new component, when trying doLayout() the error 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined** 
occurs.

The code that creates the window is:

```
    function createWindowConf(id, winconf, items) {
        var conf = {
            id: id,
            title: winconf.title, 
            iconCls: winconf.icon,
            x : winconf.xpos,
            y : winconf.ypos,
            width : parseInt(winconf.xsize), 
            height : parseInt(winconf.ysize),
            layout : winconf.layout, //'border',
            border : false,
            resizable : winconf.resizable,
            manager: windows,
            shadow: false,
            closable: true,
            items: items
        };
        var win = new Ext.Window(conf);
        win.render(desktopEl);
        return win;
    };
```

The items are a Ext.grid.GridPanel and a Ext.form.FormPanel.
According to user's current selection in grip (component in position 0) the old form should be removed and a new should be added (component in position 1).

The code that creates the form is:

```
    var theConfig = {
    id: config.yid, 
            bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
            width: 370,
            maxWidth: 370,//not resizable
            minWidth: 370,
            layout: 'form',
            margins: '0 0 0',
            region: 'east',
            split: true,
            colapsible : true,
            trackResetOnLoad: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            fieldDefaults: {
                msgTarget: 'side',
                labelWidth: 75
            },
            items: [],
            buttons: [scopeDetails.updateButton, scopeDetails.submitButton]
    };
    this.detailsForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel(theConfig);
```

and the items added afterwards.

The code that updates (adds/removes) components from the window is:

```
    this.updateWin = function(moduleForRemoveId, form, idWin) {
        var win = this.getWindow(idWin);
        if (win != null) {
            win.remove(moduleForRemoveId); 
            win.add(form);
            win.doLayout();
        }
    }
```

and produces the error in win.doLayout().

By removing all components and add the add the new ones:

```
    win.removeAll();
    win.add(this.grid);
    win.add(this.form);
    win.doLayout();
```

we have the same error.

Any suggestion will be really helpful since more than 3 days spent for that error

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the error comes from something else rather than the component remove/add.
I created a simple [testcase](http://bit.ly/URDFDk) which defines a window with a form and a grid, and a button which replaces everything with a panel. And it works.

Your code is incomplete. You should provide a full example.
Have you tried to debug it yourself? Enable "pause on uncaught exceptions" on your Chrome script debugger the reproduce the bug. You will get a stack trace of what happened, giving you hints on what is wrong. Of course include ext-all-debug.